# SQL Server 2016 : array of numbers in JSON format

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I need to create an array of numbers in JSON format in SQL Server 2016. To address the issue I created a sample table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp (Id int, Coefficient float)

INSERT into Temp VALUES (1, 0.25), (2, 1.25), (3, 0.44)
```

Since we do not have array data type, I made a query to convert the column to a "String" array and formatted it as JSON:

```
DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @CSV = COALESCE(@CSV + ', ', '') + CONVERT(varchar(10), Coefficient)  from Temp 
SELECT @CSV = '['+@CSV +']'
SELECT @CSV AS Result For JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The result is:

```
{"Result":"[0.25, 1.25, 0.44]"}
```

But it should be:

```
{"Result":[0.25, 1.25, 0.44]}
```

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified the query as follows:

```
DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @CSV1 VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @CSV = COALESCE(@CSV + ', ', '') + CONVERT(varchar(10), Coefficient) from Temp 
SELECT @CSV = '['+@CSV +']'
SELECT @CSV1= (SELECT @CSV AS Result For JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) 
SELECT REPLACE (REPLACE(@CSV1,'"[','['),']"',']');
```

It works as expected.